# moving layer doesn't seem smooth in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, layer, cocos2d-x

I have a code like below

```
if(condition)
  sprite->setPosition(newPosition)
else
  layer->moveBy(diff)
```

it works ok, but movement is not smooth..
(the code tries to keep the sprite in center while the sprite is not near the bounds of layer)

setPosition() and moveBy() is called in alternate and I think that's causing the non-smoothness.

```
1. move layer and sprite is also off the center.  
2. move sprite to center
1. go back to 1.
```

How can I fix this?
I wonder if I can move layer with leaving the sprite in the center of screen alone.

Comment: Do not use CCMove* actions for such things. They don't handle frequent changes in direction well since there's a built-in 1-frame delay before the action does anything. There's a good chance that if you add a new MoveTo action every frame, the node won't move at all. And if you don't cancel previous moves, they will influence each other and cause all kind of wackiness.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. 'moveBy' in my code snippet wasn't actually CCAction. It 's just c++ function that set's position by diff vector.  I solved the un-smoothness by setting both sprite's position and layer's position in 'else' block.